# Prevent Exceeding of Potentiometer Power Rating

Tags: led, batteries, circuit-analysis, potentiometer, digital-potentiometer

I am using a 10k digital potentiometer to adjust the brightness of an LED.
However, I need to make sure that when I reduce the resistance on the pot, it will not exceed the maximum power ratings.

The max power the pot can handle is 473mW.

So using P = I^2R, we get Imax = 6.88mA.

The battery is 3.3V

From here I am stuck and unsure how to move forward with those values.
I have a circuit like this (10k, not 1k):
[image: Circuit]
But according to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/225149), that circuit seems to be called the 'pot smoker'
How can I make sure that I do not blow out the pot?
Is there a circuit I can create to put in between the pot and the LED?

Thank you!

Comment: Add a series resistor that sets a minimum bound on the total series resistance.

Comment: @uint128_t great, I was on the right track. I was thinking of putting a 5kohm resistor there, but is there a mathematical way of determining the correct size resistor to put there to ensure I would not exceed power ratings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUKoJ2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Current limiting simplicity: add R2.*

Let's check your maths: from \$ P = I^2R \$ we can get \$ I_{MAX} = \sqrt {\frac {P}{R}} = \sqrt {\frac {0.473}{10000}} = \sqrt {0.0000473} = 6.9~mA \$, as you correctly calculated. Let's be conservative and round down to 6 mA.

The maximum current for a visible LED will be in the case of a red one as red has the lowest forward voltage drop - typically about 1.8 V at a reasonable brightness. That leaves us with 1.5 V to drop across the series resistor at 6 mA. Mr. Ohm says \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {1.5}{6m} = 267~\Omega \$ which we will round up again to the nearest value of 270 Ω.

Simply pop this somewhere in the circuit to set the minimum resistance in the circuit to a safe value for the pot.

Thanks for the reference to my pot smoker.

Comment: the pot I am using is 10k not 1k which is where i got the 6.88mA Value. However, plugging that value into your calculations yeilds 1.5V/6mA = 250ohms. (6mA for to be conservative). Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: I missed that in the text and only read the 1 k in my original schematic. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

You should place a series resistor to limit maximum current. Eventually could add an emitter follower to increase maximum current.

Comment: great, I was on the right track. I was thinking of putting a 5kohm resistor there, but is there a mathematical way of determining the correct size resistor to put there to ensure I would not exceed power ratings?