# What is max current of potentiometer?

Tags: potentiometer

I'm using 0.2 W, 500 Ω potentiometer with 300mA safely (there is no heat or abnormal behavior).
But according to calculation, max current of this potentiometer is about 20mA. Is my calculation wrong?

$$P = VI = I^2 R$$
$$0.2W = I^2 500 \Omega$$
$$I = \sqrt{\frac{0.2W}{500\Omega}} = 0.02A$$

**Edit:**

I'm confused about power rating of potentiometer. It's max value is 500 Ω and power rating is 0.2 W, so max current is 20 mA. But when I use only part of the potentiometer, 20 mA limit can be applied? I'm using 3 Ω part with 300 mA.

**Edit:**

Entire circuit is like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMXCe5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are 40 set of R - LED - LED totally. 
The current of each set is about 7 mA. (I measured voltage across the 100 Ω resistors and it's 0.7 V) And I measured current between P1 and 40 (R - LED - LED) s and it was about 280 mA. I used pot for brightness control.

Edit:

[image]

I used only 2 part of the pot. Is this not recommended? Why? (I'm just hobbyist and forgive me if this is too basic question)

This is test video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su1ZFqXYfIE
The voltage seen on the multimeter is the voltage across a 100 Ω resistor, as shown on the circuit diagram.

Comment: So to get 300mA you must be applying 150 V across the pot. (V= IR = 300 x 500 /1000 = 150 V )

Comment: Your calculation is correct; P=I^2R, so current at max power dissipation is 20mA. As Jim says though, you're apply 150 V across the potentiometer? How are you measuring the current? What voltage do you think you're putting across it? Is this AC or DC?

Comment: I'm using part of potentiometer(about 3ohm).  So voltage across potentiometer is about 0.3v(0.3^2 * 3). I'm confusing about the meaning of power rating. Power source is DC and current is measured with multimeter(serial connection)

Comment: _"I'm using 0.2W, 500ohm potentiometer with 300mA safely ..."_ - No, you're not.

Comment: 0.3V across the 500 Ohm pot gives 0.6mA (that's fine). However, if you are getting 0.3V out over a 3 Ohm section then I = V/R = 0.3 / 3 = 100mA. (Bad - magic blue smoke alert.) This would mean a voltage across the pot of 100x 500/1000 or 50 V - I don't think so.

Comment: Sorry for my basic mistake. Voltage across 3 ohm part of the potentiometer is 0.9V(0.3A * 3ohm)

Comment: I'm confused about power rating of potentiometer. It's max value is 500 ohm and power rating is 0.2W, so max current is 20mA. But when I use only part of the potentiometer, 20mA limit can be applied? I'm using 3 ohm part with 300mA.

Comment: How do you know it's 300 mA? Have you measured it? Through the _right_ path?

Comment: If you can edit your question and add a little schematic including how you are measuring the current then it will save everyone a lot of time

Comment: I added circuit schemetic.

Comment: Your schematic shows no connection to the pot wiper/tap.  And even if it did, your circuit is an abuse of the pot and NOT recommended.

Comment: Not only is it abused, it's likely not the actual circuit - if there's 0.7 volt across the 100 ohm resistors, there must be _a lot_ more across the potentiometer - definitely nothing left to turn on the LEDs.

Comment: I added additional info.

Comment: I changed the schematic to match what I _think_ is how you connected it.

Comment: And I added the meters. The ammeter is in series (not serial) and the voltmeter is in parallel with one of the 100 Ω resistors as I think you have done. Please correct any misinterpretation.

Comment: Just a general comment: Here are a couple of similar questions about applying the power ratings of potentiometers, which aren't currently shown in the "related questions" section on the page - so for anyone interested in this general subject who wants to read more, these are the links: [Burned out potentiometer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/225146/) | [A question on using potentiometer as a variable resistor](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/233874/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm using 0.2W, 500ohm potentiometer ... But according to calculation, max current of this potentiometer is about 20mA.

$$ I_{MAX} = \sqrt {\frac {P}{R}} = \sqrt {\frac {0.2}{500}} = 20~mA $$

Your calculation is correct.

You need to remember that this is the maximum current that can run through *any* portion of the potentiometer track. A common mistake is to think that if the pot was turned down to 20% that we could run five times the current through it and remain within the power limit.

[image]

*Figure 1. Single-turn potentiometer with metal casing removed to expose wiper contacts and resistive track. Source: Photo by Junkyardsparkle, [Wikipedia Commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometer#/media/File:Single-turn_potentiometer_with_internals_exposed,_oblique_view.jpg).*

It should be obvious from the photo that we can't expect to dissipate 100% of the power rating in a fraction of the potentiometer. That portion of the track would overheat.

The power rating is a useful number for the manufacturer as they can make a range of values sharing the common design. For the user the maximum current may be a more relevant parameter.

> I'm using 3 ohm part with 300 mA.

We're all surprised the potentiometer still works. You may be fortunate that at minimum setting the metal contacts are touching the tab and giving you a few ohms resistance.

You are using the potentiometer as a "rheostat" - a variable resistor rather than varying the potential or voltage *along* the track. That's OK but not at the current you are putting through that potentiometer.

> This is [test video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su1ZFqXYfIE). The voltage of multimeter is voltage aroung 100 ohm resistor.

Presuming you mean the "voltage across" one of the 100 Ω resistors. In the video this varies from about 13 mV to 400 mV which means your current through that leg of the circuit (one pair of LEDs) is varying (using I = V/R) from 0.13 mA to 4 mA.

Comment: @firia2000: See update.

Comment: Thank you for kind explanation. The video is vcc downed version so current through pot is 4*40=160mA. But this value is still 8 times of max current. Am I just fortunate? Is this really possible?

Comment: You might get away with it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

The first tab on the potentiometer that you did not connect is the ground and allows you to put the resistance all the way to zero.